# Fluid app doesn't save cookies

Tags: cookies, fluid.app

I've got several Fluid apps for Amazon Web Services consoles (on different accounts).

The aws console saves UI preferences between sessions (e.g., which columns in a display do I want to see).  I believe but am not 100% sure that this is stored in a cookie.

When I use firefox, this preference is saved between browser sessions.  In the fluid app, it is not.

I found the directory `~/Library/Application Support/Fluid/FluidApps/AWS-DEV Console`.  It has a `cookies` directory, which is empty.  Other things are being successfully saved in this directory (`Bookmarks, DownloadArchive, webhistory`).

At some point I discovered that Fluid was being sandboxed (I think; when I ran fluid apps i got a separate mounted pseudo-filesystem).  The fluid apps had the finder attribute com.apple.quarantine set.  I removed that with xattr and I no longer am in the sandbox.  No effect on the cookies.

Fluid Version 1.8.6 (2331).  I have purchased a license key, which is installed.

MacOS version 10.13.1 (17B48).

Is this a bug, or am I doing something silly?

---

edit:  It appears that the preference is saved in HTML5 local storage, not in a traditional cookie. I'm guessing fluid apps don't implement this.

Comment: I have this trouble too. Developer hasn't written back.

Comment: It's supposed to save cookies in the paid version. It's probably  a bug, contact the developer.

Comment: I gave up on fluid.  I am using Unite in its place. It's not perfect but it works well enough.